# Zillow API returning 410 response

Tags: zillow

Just recently a script that has been running flawlessly has begun to return a 410 response to the HTML get call to both the http://www.zillow.com/webservice/GetSearchResults.htm and the http://www.zillow.com/webservice/GetDeepSearchResults.htm

Pasting the url that the script is fetching into the browser gives the same 410 error, as though they have removed it entirely.

I see references to their new Bridge API, but no notifications that their old API was being discontinued that I can find.  Any insight?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions/255746#255746)

Comment: @Rob The Zillow API is a pretty established API and one that is widely used amongst real estate app developers.  It is integral to many functions of a significant number of apps and for it to go offline with no announcement warrants discussion, particularly if there is no currently published information about the API's demise.  It took me a while to figure out what was going on because I never programmed in a 410 response to my code.  If this is indeed the result of a shut-down there are going to be a lot of developers that will be scrambling.

Comment: @Rob I'm facing the same issue. Out of the blue the API has stopped working and returning 410 gone.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue. It looks like it might be shut down on the 25th/26th.

Comment: I have applied for the new Zillow Group Bridge API (https://www.bridgeinteractive.com/developers/zillow-group-data/) which appears to be very similar to the previous APIs, but consolidated.  Appears to have the same use limitations, however, it's a manual process to apply for an API key as opposed to the previous automatic process.  Received an email response 7 days later asking for my use case and have not heard anything since (8 days ago).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Zillow has shut down all of their data APIs as of the end of February.  As was stated in another answer, it appears as though they shut it down as a result of abuse, but did so with no mention of it at all (as a matter of fact, the documentation and sign up remain active to this day, nearly 3 weeks after the API began throwing 410 response codes).

In 2016 Zillow purchased Bridge Interactive, which is a company that specializes in Broker and MLS back-office solutions and data management.  [see press release here](https://www.prnewswire.com/news-releases/zillow-group-acquires-bridge-interactive-group-300307361.html)

Bridge Interactive now has the Zestimates API ([see documentation here](https://bridgedataoutput.com/docs/explorer/zestimates)) along with a new API that appears to offer API access to public data too ([Public Data API docs](https://bridgedataoutput.com/docs/explorer/public-data))

I had applied for access to the Bridge API in February using their [web form on the Bridge Interactive Website](https://www.bridgeinteractive.com/resources/api-documentation/) shortly after the demise of the Zillow APIs and after about 2 weeks and a bit of back-and forth via email I just got my invite to access the Bridge API.

It does appear to have the same restrictions as the Zillow API just on their new platform.  Sign-up is a manual process so it takes some time but, knock on wood, I might be back up and running in a short period of time after integrating with the new API (which, of course, is completely different than the Zillow APIs).

**Update 2021-03-28**

It appears as though on or about March 26th, their API began to respond again -- I have tested the getSearchResults and the Zestimate API and both are responding as they previously had.

Comment: Could you provide the link? and any advice on how to get approved (besides having an agent as a web development client, which I've got)? thanks

Comment: As of 05/16/2022, I get the same 410 error.

Comment: Any update for November 2022? I tried and received a 410 response too

Answer (score 6):

According to this tweet from Zillow in response to a customer question, it looks like their API has been turned off due to customer misuse.

https://twitter.com/zillow/status/1365418247949058048